# Limpar textearea vindo do Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, textarea

Estou com o seguinte cenário, usando o Plugin `summernote` para um `textarea` com as configurações:

```
<textarea id="summernote" name="editordata">{{$termos->termos}}</textarea>
```

Ele retorna dos dados corretamente do banco, porem estou criando um buttom para tentar limpar os dados caso o cliente queira reescrever.

Linha de código:

```
<button type="button" class="text-center btn btn-warning" id="limpar">Limpar</button>
```

E o `jQuery` esta da seguinte forma:

```
$('#limpar').click(function() {
    $('#summernote').val(" ");
});
```

Tentei o `empyt()` também sem sucesso, alguém teria alguma solução para esse impasse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a documentação vc precisa fazer um `reset` https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#reset

> Reset: Clear the editor content and remove all stored history.

Então sei script deveria ficar assim

```
$('#limpar').click(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote('reset');
});
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado

Comment: @BetiniO.Heleno sem problemas meu caro []´s